# Blender model losing faces in unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to import blender model(character with armature) to unity and in unity some model faces are lost, how to fix this? [image: Model in blender] [image: Model in unity] [image: Model in unity]

Comment: I guess they are not lost, could it be that Unity has backface culling enabled by default? Maybe those faces are flipped?

Comment: Yes you probably need to recalculate the faces normals in Blender (Edit mode > Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside)

Comment: 100% that. The mesh also has interior faces it seems which can be detrimental to shading

Comment: ok I'm really confused right now, I tried recalculating it inside in that leg that problem happens and now it works, I'm really bad at this staff can anyone explain why it works now when normals are faceing inside? now in unity faces are showing but now they are black.
https://imgur.com/a/hzTc3xg